# JQuery AJAX DataTable Not Loading Standard Functions After Reload Data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have added DataTables to a table i am fetching data via AJAX, using PHP and SQL. On the very first load, after performing the first Search all is fine and everything works as intended. However when searching a second time, while all the code used to Search has been ran through again, the DataTable functionality seems to stop working.

I added some alerts into crucial parts in the DataTable file, and found after the first search, it never makes it back into the file.

I though maybe i need to  "re-initialise" DataTable seeing as the entirety of the data contents has changed after my search again.

Spent a long time looking online, with a lot of suggestions being around Destroy and Clear etc. But nothing seems to work.

Here is my code, as you can see i have it set to do something different after the first search but not sure how to fix this, as the sorting, pagination, searching etc all dont work:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/ITSMIS/data/asset/search.php',
    data:HardwareAsset,
    dataType: "html",
    success:function(data){

        LoadDataTableHeaders();

        var NotSearched = document.getElementById("no-search-default");
        var TableContainer = document.getElementById("data-table-container");
        var NoSearchResults = document.getElementById("no-search-results");

        if(NotSearched.style.display !== 'none'){
            $(NotSearched).hide();
        }
        if(data){
            if(TableContainer.style.display == 'none'){
                $(TableContainer).show();
            }
            $(NoSearchResults).hide();
            $('#data-table-results').html(data);

            $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
                var DataTableColumn = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
                $(DataTableColumn).remove();
            });

            if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#data-table' ) ) {
                $('#data-table').DataTable();
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        else{
            if(NoSearchResults.style.display == 'none'){
                $(TableContainer).hide();
                $(NoSearchResults).show();
            }   
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: If  you are going to dump the data into the raw html table, you will need to invalidate and redraw all of the rows. DataTable does not know you are changing the underlying html

Comment: you could always destroy and rebuild the entire table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should invalidate and redraw the table when it already exits.
(Added 'full-rest' parameter after I found this: https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())

```
if (  $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#data-table' ) ) {
     $('#data-table').DataTable().rows().invalidate().draw('full-reset');
 }
 else{
      $('#data-table').DataTable();
 }
```

Comment: Okay this seems to have fixed pagination, and the row count option, search also seems good. but sort still seems to not reload. Thanks a lot for the fix for the rest though! much appreciated.

Comment: You could always destroy and rebuild the table on each ajax call

Answer (score 1):

You could try simply re-initializing Datatables by calling

```
$('#data-table').DataTable({
    destroy: true
});
```

this option would allow Datatables to destroy the previous instance if it exists, and initialize as if it was the first time.